# Change in nvd3 graph only when screen size is adjusted

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have page with a set of input radio options and a nvd3 graph. I want that when the user clicks one of the radio options the graph represents the values of that radio option. I found how to do that with the help of [Strange functionality of NVD3 Graph when updating data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130835/strange-functionality-of-nvd3-graph-when-updating-data)
Only my code doesn't work 100%. The data in the graph is only updated after resizing the screen. What am I missing here?

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/h4tzLd1u/3/

```
var staafgrafiek;
var chartData;
nv.addGraph(function () {
var width = 320,
height = 300;
var staafgrafiek = nv.models.multiBarChart();
staafgrafiek.showControls(false)
staafgrafiek.groupSpacing(0.05)
staafgrafiek.reduceXTicks(false)
staafgrafiek.yAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {
return '€' + d3.format('s')(d)
})
staafgrafiek.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.0f'))
staafgrafiek.width(width)
staafgrafiek.height(height)

var data_2011 = [{
key: "Salary",
color: "#d96704",
values: [{
x: 2011,
y: 38788
}, {
x: 2012,
y: 2001
}, {
x: 2013,
y: 50000
}]
}, {
key: "Adjusted",
color: "#3c8c30",
values: [{
x: 2011,
y: 30263
}, {
x: 2012,
y: 30263
}, {
x: 2013,
y: 30263
}]
}];

chartData = d3.select('#staafgrafiek svg').datum(data_2011);
chartData.transition().duration(1000).call(staafgrafiek).attr('width', width).attr('height', height);


nv.utils.windowResize(staafgrafiek.update);

return staafgrafiek;
});

var data_2009 = [{
key: "Salary",
color: "#d96704",
values: [{
x: 2009,
y: 5000
}, {
x: 2010,
y: 25000
}, {
x: 2011,
y: 3000
}]
}, {
key: "Adjusted",
color: "#3c8c30",
values: [{
x: 2009,
y: 22002
}, {
x: 2010,
y: 22002
}, {
x: 2011,
y: 22002
}]
}];

function update_2009() {

chartData.datum(data_2009).transition().duration(1000).call(staafgrafiek);
nv.utils.windowResize(staafgrafiek.update);

};

d3.select("#input_2009").on("click", update_2009);

var data_2010 = [{
key: "Salary",
color: "#d96704",
values: [{
x: 2010,
y: 25000
}, {
x: 2011,
y: 3000
}, {
x: 2012,
y: 2001
}]
}, {
key: "Adjusted",
color: "#3c8c30",
values: [{
x: 2010,
y: 21000
}, {
x: 2011,
y: 21000
}, {
x: 2012,
y: 21000
}]
}];

function update_2010() {

chartData.datum(data_2010).transition().duration(1000).call(staafgrafiek);
nv.utils.windowResize(staafgrafiek.update);

};

d3.select("#input_2010").on("click", update_2010);

var data_2011 = [{
key: "Inkomen uit werk en woning",
color: "#d96704",
values: [{
x: 2011,
y: 38788
}, {
x: 2012,
y: 2001
}, {
x: 2013,
y: 50000
}]
}, {
key: "Adjusted",
color: "#3c8c30",
values: [{
x: 2011,
y: 30263
}, {
x: 2012,
y: 30263
}, {
x: 2013,
y: 30263
}]
}];
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it eventually.

```
var data_2009
```

and

```
var data_2010
```

should be placed in the update part. Not outside it.
e.g.

```
function update_2010() {

var data_2010 = [{
key: "Salary",
color: "#d96704",
values: [{
x: 2010,
y: 25000
}, {
x: 2011,
y: 3000
}, {
x: 2012,
y: 2001
}]
}, {
key: "Adjusted",
color: "#3c8c30",
values: [{
x: 2010,
y: 21000
}, {
x: 2011,
y: 21000
}, {
x: 2012,
y: 21000
}]
}];

chartData.datum(data_2010).transition().duration(1000).call(staafgrafiek);
nv.utils.windowResize(staafgrafiek.update);

};
```