# intergrating sliders in nvd3 barcharts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, nvd3.js

Ive managed to update the first few bars to have values changed manually by sliders on a normal javascript barchart.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZmnWq/68/

HTML

```
<div style="margin: 20px 0px 0px 60px">
    <form oninput="output1.value=slider1.value">
        <input type="range" name="slider1" id="slider1"/>
        <output name="output1" for="slider1"></output>
    </form>
    <form oninput="output2.value=slider2.value">
        <input type="range" name="slider2" id="slider2"/>
        <output name="output2" for="slider2"></output>
    </form>

<button id="updater">Update</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                var chartColumn = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'chart-column',
                        type: 'column',
                        backgroundColor: null
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Percentage of rainfall'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: [
                            'Jan',
                            'Feb',
                            'Mar',
                            'Apr',
                            'May',
                            'Jun',
                            'Jul',
                            'Aug',
                            'Sep',
                            'Oct',
                            'Nov',
                            'Dec'
                        ]
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        max: 100,
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false,
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        align: 'left',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: 100,
                        y: 70,
                        floating: true,
                        shadow: true
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return ''+
                                this.x +': '+ this.y +' mm';
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                            pointPadding: 0.2,
                            borderWidth: 0
                        }
                    },
                        series: [{
                        name: 'Air Consumption',
                        data: [42, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

                    }]
                });

                var $slider = $("#updater");

                    $slider.bind('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                        chartColumn.series[0].data[0].update(parseInt($("#slider1").val()));
                        chartColumn.series[0].data[1].update(parseInt($("#slider2").val()));
                });
            });
```

CSS

```
body { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; }
input[type="range"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: rgb(144, 144, 144);
    height: 3px;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 11px;
    height: 15px;
    border:solid black 1px;
    background:#ffffff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}
```

But i want to be able to make a better looking graph provided by nvd3
What i've managed to do is change an example to this

http://jsfiddle.net/0zsdmpd2/7/

HTML

```
<div id="chart">
    <svg></svg>
</div>
</div>
<form oninput="output1.value=slider1.value">
    <input type="range" name="slider1" id="slider1" />
    <output name="output1" for="slider1"></output>
</form>
<form oninput="output2.value=slider2.value">
    <input type="range" name="slider2" id="slider2" />
    <output name="output2" for="slider2"></output>
</form>
<button id="updater">Update</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
    var data = [
    [{
        "key": "Previous","values": 
        [
            ['Resistance', 41.27, 0],
            ['fuel consumed', 47.96, 1],
            ['fuel cost', 44.65, 2]

        ]
    }, {
        "key": "Current","values": 
        [
            ['Resistance', 40.48, 0],
            ['fuel consumed', 45.82, 1],
            ['fuel cost', 40.16, 2]

        ]
    }]
];

var n = 0;

nv.addGraph(function () {
    var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
        .x(function (d) {
        return d[0];
    })
        .y(function (d) {
        return d[1];
    })
        .color(['#84c1ea', '#1f77b4'])
        .forceY([0, 100])
        .reduceXTicks(false)
        .stacked(false)
        .showControls(false)
        .margin({
        left: 50,
        right: 30
    });

    chart.xAxis.showMaxMin(true)
        .tickFormat['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'];


    chart.yAxis.tickFormat['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'];
    d3.select("#chart svg")
        .datum(data[n])
        .transition().duration(500).call(chart);


                var $slider = $("#updater");

                    $slider.bind('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                        chartColumn.Previous[0].values[0].update(parseInt($("#slider1").val()));
                        chartColumn.Previous[0].values[1].update(parseInt($("#slider2").val()));
                });


});

Css

    #chart svg {
        height: 400px;
    }

However, I have no idea how to use the slider to manually update the values in the graph inside the nvd3 barchart. The update button not updating the values.
```

Any help is deeply appreciated, as i am new to html and javascript coding, but trying to do my best to complete a job given to me.

(updated nvd3 jsfiddle graph)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NVD3 - How to refresh the data function to product new data on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689157/nvd3-how-to-refresh-the-data-function-to-product-new-data-on-click)

Comment: Sorry if im asking dumb questions btw cause i really have no dealings with d3.js before. Cause in that questions it seems they're using loop to go through the rows of their own formula.

But if my code has hardcoded data inside, how do i create a path to update the value individually using the slider? Really sorry for bothering you with something quite simple, i dont really know looping too well